# Where is sideshow in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I can't find sideshow in Windows 7 RC. Is that feature gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it’s hidden until you install a device compatible with Sideshow.

see: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2345970,00.asp